# Fill the textbox from databse on dropdown change

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want fill the **text-box value** from the database on the basis of  **on change** event of drop-down list  in php

Actually my work flow is when i select a value by drop-down list, on the base of that selected value (on-change event) the filtered record should be in the text box using php

```
<head>
<script>

function SelectedTemplate()
{
    what type of code i have to there?![for detail please see image i have posted][1]


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbltemplate where UserName = '$name' " );
    if($result != '')
    {   
        while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
    echo'<option value="' .$test['TempID']. '">' .$test['TempTitle']. '</option>';
    }
    }
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the data from the database and put into variables and then add the variables to the textbox value. **Please post your code to let me solve your problem easily**

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax for this. ( value comes after you make a select from dropdown box ) 
Here is it all explained:

[Using AJAX to return query results based on drop down box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770731/using-ajax-to-return-query-results-based-on-drop-down-box)

BR's